# How does property length work?

Tags: javascript

When i loop in a list with several items and use property length does the length property get only the longest word or does it get length of all items?

```
function onS() {
var maxLength = 0;
var longestListTitle = "";
var Enum = list.getEnumerator();
while (Enum.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
    var listTitle = currentItem.get_title();
    if (listTitle.length > maxLength) {
        longestListTitle = listTitle;
        maxLength = longestListTitle.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

length works differently on String or Array.

On a string, length is the total length of the string with all caracters. `"test test".length` will give you 9.

On a array, it can be more tricky. `[].length` is obvioulsy 0. `['test'].length` is 1. But you can do this :

```
var test = [];
test[0] = 1;
test[10] = 2;
console.log(test.length); // output 11
```

For an array, `length` is the maximum index used + 1.

Answer (score 1):

If its an `array` it will give you the length of the array (total elements in array). If its a string, it gives you the length of the string (total characters in the string.)